# How to change color of numbers in text in excel

Tags: excel

I want to change the color of numeric value to green if its positive and red if negative. But the problem is values are inside text. How can I do it with excel?

```
 Account Balance : 3456 
 Account Balance : -4566
```

Then 3456 should be in green and -4566 in red

Answer (score 0):

If your data is always in the format of

> Account Balance : 3456
>
> Account Balance : -4566

Then you could just do conditional formatting -> highlight cells rules -> text that contains -> -